# App not appearing in "Open in" menu

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sharing

I'm trying to make my app capable of opening audio files from other apps.
I have made additions to `info.plist` file, but it didn't help.

Below is info in `Info.plist` related to sharing:

```xml
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Icon-App.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>AudioFile</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.ulaw-audio</string>
                <string>public.aiff-audio</string>
                <string>public.mpeg-4-audio </string>
                <string>public.mp3</string>
                <string>public.audio</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

What changes should be made and how and where do I handle input data that comes from outside of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Register the URL Scheme for Audio, then it will show in the list

Comment: Isn't it what the `<string>public.audio</string>` line already does in OP's Info.plist? If not, how would they do it?